# Issue with System.Web.WebPages after installing MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have installed MVC4 and an MVC3 app that I have is now causing me problems.  I get the error :

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

However, I cannot find any references in my code to v2 of WebPages, and I am wondering why I am getting this error.  Can anybody help?

EDIT : Here is the full stack trace :

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   ljMVC.Helpers.EditableHelpers.Editable(HtmlHelper helper, String htmlElement, String cssId, String defaultContent, Object htmlAttributes) in C:\Users\M\Desktop\Development\ASP.NET projects\ljMVC\ljMVC\ljMVC\Helpers\EditableHelpers.cs:90
   ASP._Page_Areas_Gameplan_Views_MainGP_Index_cshtml.Execute() in e:\web\lovelyjubbl\htdocs\Areas\Gameplan\Views\MainGP\Index.cshtml:85
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +208
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +89
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +199
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1c.b*_19() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +264
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b() +20
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +176
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +329
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +94
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassb.b*_5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClasse.b_*d() +31
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b*_0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970061
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace. The part containing `calling assembly` is particularly interesting as it will give you indication which assembly is attempting to load this assembly. And you must have done something with this ASP.NET MVC 3 application. What is it? Just installing ASP.NET MVC 4 won't have any effect on existing applications. I am sure you have modified something. Like installing/updating a NuGet or something in this MVC 3 application. It just won't break by itself. I have like gazillions of MVC 3 applications and after installing MVC 4 all of them continue to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
EditableHelpers.cs:90
```

I guess you are using some NuGet or something that depends on WebPages 2.0 (a.k.a `System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0`). You probably updated this NuGet or whatever it is and now you have dependency with this assembly.

Comment: Strange as I am pretty sure I have not changed this class since installing MVC4

Comment: I doubt it very much. Installing MVC 4 wouldn't break any existing MVC 3 applications, I could guarantee you this from my experience. When I installed MVC 4 on my computer I've had lots of existing applications and all of them continued to work flawlessly.

Comment: Looks like this was caused by NuGet updating my WebPages reference from v1 to v2.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I knew it. I knew that you touched it :-) I was ready to bet like 5 bucks.

Comment: @Darin: Similar thing happened to me. On my dev box I installed 4.5 and MVC4, but not on the server. An MVC3 app that ran fine on the dev box gave me this same error on the server. I didn't run any NuGet update -- not sure if it does anything automatically. I noticed that System.Web.WebPages was pointing to v2.0 on dev. To fix I had to edit the csproj and specify that it should use v1.0, recompile, and redeploy. It had no version specified, so I'm guessing it was using v2.0 by default on dev and when compiled it was hardcoding v2 in the final dll, and since v2 was not on the server...